# Validation of Controlvalue with binding in Property Setter

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, mvvm, binding

I have a normal TextBox in Silverlight and the text in bound to models property. In the Setter of the property I check for some rules. If the rules say that value is invalid then I do not set the new value (instead the old one will be left or an other one).

Is there any way to inform the UI's TextBox that value changed. Because there is the only place in this Situation where the value is shown incorrect 
(I tried ValidatesOnExceptions on BindingExpression and throw an exception in property, but nothing happened).

I know that using IValidation-Interface's is a better way. But for my current archytecture the above Scenario seems to be better.

Comment: If I understand correctly, did you try INotifyPropertyChanged interface? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: YoYo is right. I would also suggest you throw an error, not just leave the old value. This will cause the control to NOT validate so they have to fix the value, avoiding the refresh issue.

Comment: The PropertyChanged-Event was raised but didn't work (because binding avoid calling back to source).
When I raise an error in setter then nothing is happen to UI-Control.